# Render an authentication protected component after an async authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-router

Expected:
the async function checks if the user is authenticated, then return true, so that the protected component gets rendered, or false, that redirects the user to the login page.

What actually happens:
the `getAuth()` function returns "Promise ", breaking the code.

```
  export default function RequireAuth({ children, redirectTo }) {
  const BASE_API_URL = "https://api-backend.test";

  const getAuth = async () => {
    const isAuth = await axios
      .get(BASE_API_URL + "/user_auth.php", {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 201) {
          return true;
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
          return false;
        }
      });

    return isAuth;
  };

  let isAuthenticated = getAuth();
  return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
}
```

This is how the "protected" component should be displayed according to the official documentation [here](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/d54b40a094277b7afdd6b81f51a0393f#route-composition-in-react-router-v6).

```
<Route
  path="/dashboard"
  element={
    <RequireAuth redirectTo="/login">
      <Dashboard />
    </RequireAuth>
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it properly using `useEffect`, try this

```
export default function RequireAuth({ children, redirectTo }) {
  const BASE_API_URL = "https://api-backend.test";
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAuth = () => {
      const isAuth = axios
        .get(BASE_API_URL + "/user_auth.php", {
          withCredentials: true
        })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.status === 201) {
            setAuthenticated(true);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.response.status === 401) {
            setAuthenticated(false);
          }
        });
    };

    getAuth();
  }, [redirectTo]);

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return children;
  }
  return <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getAuth` is an async function, so it will return a Promise. You have to either `await` its output or use `.then` to work with the resolved promise.

Side note, it's usually preferable to either use `async/await` or `.then`, but not both.